# Adding dictonary values while using HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, httpresponse

I want to redirect to the existing page and display a queryset which would be determined based on the values submitted via the form. The dictionary values I get from function `get_context_data` display correctly. The dictionary values I try and add in the `post` function do not display correctly.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    RoomBookingsForm    = BookRoomsForm(request.POST or None)
    self.object = self.get_object() # assign the object to the view
    context = self.get_context_data( *args, **kwargs)

    context.update({'room_type_queryset': RoomType.objects.all().filter()})

    print("all context values")
    print(context)

    if request.method == 'POST':
    
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info, context )
```

As well as `context.update` I also tried  `context['room_type_queryset'] = RoomType.objects.all().filter()`

Based on the two print statements above I got

```
all context values
{'object': <AmericanHotel: Caesars Palace>, 'americanhotel': <AmericanHotel: Caesars Palace>, 'slug': 'caesars-palace', 'view': <hotel.views.HotelDetailSlugView object at 0x00000210575117F0>, 'cart': <Cart: 5>, 'hotel_extra_photos': <QuerySet [<AmericanHotelPhoto: Caesars Palace>, <AmericanHotelPhoto: Caesars Palace>, <AmericanHotelPhoto: Caesars Palace>, <AmericanHotelPhoto: Caesars Palace>, <AmericanHotelPhoto: Caesars Palace>, <AmericanHotelPhoto: Caesars Palace>, <AmericanHotelPhoto: Caesars Palace>, <AmericanHotelPhoto: Caesars Palace>, <AmericanHotelPhoto: Caesars Palace>]>, 'room_type': <QuerySet [<RoomType: Caesars Palace, Triple>, <RoomType: Caesars Palace, Double>]>, 'room_type_queryset': <QuerySet [<RoomType: Caesars Palace, Double>, <RoomType: Caesars Palace, Triple>]>}
```

The results from `room_type` are correctly displayed in red.

```
{% for instance in room_type %}
     <H1 style="color:red">{{instance}}</H1>
{% endfor %}
```

The results from `room_type_queryset`  do not appear.

```
{% for instance in room_type_queryset %}
    <H1 style="color:blue">{{instance}}</H1>
{% endfor %}
```

**Update**

I made a few modifications to my code but based on the screenshot you can see I am still having problems.

[image]

```
   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            RoomBookingsForm    = BookRoomsForm(request.POST or None)
            self.object = self.get_object() # assign the object to the view
            context = self.get_context_data( *args, **kwargs)
            context['room_type_results'] = RoomType.objects.all().filter()
<h1>Will the results appear</h1>
<h1>{{room_type_results}}</h1>
<p1>{{room_type_results}}</p1>
{{room_type_results}}
<h1>End of will the results appear</h1>
```

Comment: If you open the developer tools in your browser, can you find the results from `room_type_queryset`? Have you tried another name (without `_queryset`) or another color?

Comment: Unfortunately I have already tried both of these suggestions.

Comment: Did you check the developer tools (Ctrl + Shift + I)? Can you show the entire dictionary (without for loop, just the whole raw json in a <p> tag)?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using

```
return render(request, self.template_name,context)
```

I didn't realise that this approach would not alter the URL. Thus using this approach meant I still had access to the slug value.

I did `print(request)` and got `<WSGIRequest: POST '/hotel/detail/caesars-palace/'>`, in this instance 'caesars-palace' is the slug value.

And I found this [comment](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/i-am-curious-about-the-difference-between-httpresponseredirect-and-render#:%7E:text=According%20to%20the%20docs%2C%20render,along%20with%20the%20new%20URL.) on another site- '*Hello! Thank you very much for your help ! :D Hmm so the difference between them is that when you get to use HttpResponse, you're sending the context dictionary with the url so that's rendered as a typical website but if you use HttpResponseRedirect, you get to send only url...? Am I getting this in a right way? :D?.... Thanks for your help again :D*'

If this is correct then I would have been unable to resolve my problem with HttpResponseRedirect.